# 404 error when I tried to use author slug in url

Tags: 404-error

basically, I created a custom physical page called (`page-team.php`) after that I created a page from the dashboard called team and assign a template to the physical page that I mention before.

I tried to use function `get_user_by( 'slug', $author_name )` by fetching value from URL (`https://my-domain/team/authorName`) usually redirects me to 404 page the only way to fetch data to use URL like this (`https://my-domain/team/?author=authorName`) by this way I can display author data in page

for SEO purposes is there any way to use the first URL (`https://my-domain/team/authorName`) than the second one

my default page (`https://my-domain/author/authorName`) working normally I need to fetch the same data to the user for the team page. Is there any way to solve this?

I appreciated any answer :)

Comment: this will require rewrite rules to do

Comment: is there any link to help me to create rules for this issue ? thanks a lot.

Comment: The docu has some examples [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) and [there](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/rewrite/), what exactly are you having problems with? With a rewrite rule, you might be possible to just use `/author/name` logic for `/team/name` URL.